# How to graph inverse cofunctions in trigonometry

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the manual, in section "94.3 Syntax for Mathematical Expressions: Functions" in the [pgfmanual](http://ctan.mirror.globo.tech/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), the inverse trig functions are there but not the inverse trig cofunctions.

I suppose they're not common enough to be given like the other functions, but I am wondering if there's a way to graph them easily? A series expansion would probably be enough for my purposes but while experimenting, I'm having a problem when it curls up and down when x is 1. Maybe I could make a function that merely looks like those inverse cofunctions?

How others would deal with this lack of function?

Comment: If you mean arccotangent, arcsecant and arccosecant, they're related to arctangent, arccosine and arcsine by simple identities.

Comment: Oh man, this is embarrassing since I could just do reciprocals inside the inverse functions

Thanks for the help! :D

Comment: For the arccotangent, the relation is not with reciprocals, but rather “arccotangent = pi/2 minus arctangent”.